# Depth limited alpha-beta in prolog

Tags: prolog, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm building a chess engine in Prolog.
The alpha-beta from "prolog programing for artificial intelligence" is not depth limited.
Since it's not possible to search the whole tree in chess I'm trying to modify the code from the book to be depth limited but it's not working properly.

here is the book code:

```
alphabeta(Pos, Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, Val) :-
   moves(Pos, PosList), !,
   boundedbest( PosList, Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, Val)
    ;
get_pos_value(Pos,Val).                             % static value of Pos

boundedbest([Pos | PosList], Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, GoodVal) :-
   alphabeta( Pos, Alpha, Beta, _, Val),
   goodenough(PosList, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, GoodPos, GoodVal).

goodenough([],_,_,Pos, Val, Pos, Val) :- !.               % no other candidate

goodenough(_, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Pos, Val) :-
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Beta, !;                  % Maximizer attained upper bound
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Alpha, !.                     % Minimizer attained lower bound

goodenough( PosList, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, GoodPos, GoodVal) :-
   newbounds( Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, NewAlpha, NewBeta),  % Refine bounds
   boundedbest(PosList, NewAlpha, NewBeta, Pos1, Val1),
   betterof( Pos, Val, Pos1, Val1, GoodPos, GoodVal).

newbounds(Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Val, Beta) :-
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Alpha, !.                    % Mazximizer increased lower bound

newbounds(Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Alpha, Val):-
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Beta, !.                     % Minimizer decreased upper bound

newbounds( Alpha, Beta, _,_,Alpha, Beta).                   % otherwise bounds unchanged.

betterof(Pos, Val, Pos1, Val1, Pos, Val) :-                 % Pos better than Pos1
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Val1, !;
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Val1, !.

betterof(_,_,Pos1,Val1,Pos1,Val1).                          % otherwise Pos 1 better
```

My attempts to modify it to be depth limited are :

```
alphabeta(Pos, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, 0) :- % max depth of search recieved
   get_pos_value(Pos,Val).                      % static value of Pos


alphabeta(Pos, Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, Val, Depth) :-
   Depth > 0,
   moves(Pos, PosList), !,
   boundedbest( PosList, Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, Val,Depth).


alphabeta(Pos, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Depth) :-
   Depth > 0,
   get_pos_value(Pos,Val).


boundedbest([Pos | PosList], Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, GoodVal,Depth) :-
   Depth is Depth - 1,
   alphabeta( Pos, Alpha, Beta, _, Val,Depth1),
   goodenough(PosList, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, GoodPos, GoodVal).

goodenough([],_,_,Pos, Val, Pos, Val) :- !.               % no other candidate

goodenough(_, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Pos, Val) :-
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Beta, !;                  % Maximizer attained upper bound
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Alpha, !.                     % Minimizer attained lower bound

goodenough( PosList, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, GoodPos, GoodVal) :-
   newbounds( Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, NewAlpha, NewBeta),  % Refine bounds
   boundedbest(PosList, NewAlpha, NewBeta, Pos1, Val1,_),
   betterof( Pos, Val, Pos1, Val1, GoodPos, GoodVal).

newbounds(Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Val, Beta) :-
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Alpha, !.                % Mazximizer increased lower bound

newbounds(Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, Alpha, Val):-
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Beta, !.                     % Minimizer decreased upper bound

newbounds( Alpha, Beta, _,_,Alpha, Beta).                   % otherwise bounds unchanged.

betterof(Pos, Val, Pos1, Val1, Pos, Val) :-                 % Pos better than Pos1
   min_to_move(Pos), Val > Val1, !;
   max_to_move(Pos), Val < Val1, !.

betterof(_,_,Pos1,Val1,Pos1,Val1).                          % otherwise Pos 1 better
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: FYI for others: "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" 4th Edition by Ivan Bratko,   Section: 24.3 The alpha-beat algorithm: an efficient implementation of minimax, page: 585

Comment: yes, the code on page 585 is not depth limited will not work for a chess game, it prunes with alpha-beta but the search is to the bottom of the tree.

Comment: Which Prolog are you using? There might be something like "call with depth limit" or similar. Like this one: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_with_depth_limit/3

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code. And more importantly, **you have a typo in your code that SWI-Prolog found and diagnosed for you.** Do not ignore its warnings.

Look:

```
Warning: /home/isabelle/chess.pl:1:
    Singleton variables: [Alpha,Beta]
Warning: /home/isabelle/chess.pl:11:
    Singleton variables: [Alpha,Beta]
Warning: /home/isabelle/chess.pl:16:
    Singleton variables: [Depth1]
Warning: /home/isabelle/chess.pl:40:
    Singleton variables: [Pos1]
```

Specifically, in this clause starting on line 16:

```
boundedbest([Pos | PosList], Alpha, Beta, GoodPos, GoodVal,Depth) :-
   Depth is Depth - 1,
   alphabeta( Pos, Alpha, Beta, _, Val,Depth1),
   goodenough(PosList, Alpha, Beta, Pos, Val, GoodPos, GoodVal).
```

your use of `Depth1` shows that you seem to understand that a new value needs to be computed and passed into the recursion. But you forgot to use this variable on the preceding line:

```
Depth is Depth - 1,
```

this should use `Depth1` in the left hand side.

It is a mistake to even try to test code that has singleton warnings, since singleton warnings are often an indication of very serious bugs. This is the case here. When you see a singleton warning, the first thing you should do is to understand and fix it---any other interaction with the program is likely meaningless.

It is true that some of these warnings are "benign": The warnings for the clause on the first line do not seem to indicate bugs in that clause. Maybe you have seen some of these warnings and decided that they are harmless. The exact opposite is the case: Accepting such "spurious" singleton warnings means that you risk serious warnings slipping in.

(I haven't tested the corrected program since it's understandably incomplete.)

Comment: Nice answer. One nice thing about Prolog warnings and bugs is that I never find them a waste of time to check out the reason. 90% of the time it is something simply wrong in my code that I did such as typo, or missing an argument or an argument in the wrong place. 8% of the time the variable just needs to be a don't care variable, e.g. `_` or `_info`, and 2% of the time I learn something seriously wrong with my algorithm.

Comment: thanks, I fixed the typo but I'm still not getting the expected results

Comment: It's hard to tell without having all of the code, the query you are running, the results you are getting, and the results you are expecting. **IF** the book's code is licensed in a way that allows you to share it online, you could put a complete example at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ and link us to it. Otherwise, any information you can add to the question without copyright infringement might help.

Comment: I just want to take that book code and modify it such that it will be depth limited